# OpenGL ES: using the screen as an input texture to a shader

Tags: opengl-es

I'd like to do the opposite of what is normally done, i.e. take the default Framebuffer (the screen), use that as an input texture in my fragment shader.

I know I can do

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0);
glReadPixels( blah,blah,blah, buf);
int texID = createTexture(buf);
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);
runShaderProgram();
```

but that's copying data that's already in the GPU to the CPU (ReadPixels) and then back to the GPU (BindTexture), isn't it?

Couldn't we somehow 'directly' use the contents of the screen and feed it to the shaders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible - the API simply doesn't expose this functionality for general purpose shader code.

If you want render to texture then is there any reason why you can't just do it the "normal" way and render to an off-screen FBO?

Comment: Thanks. There's no 'strong' reason for me not to use to 'normal' way. I am writing a kind of OpenGL library and my API would just be cleaner if, wherever it accepts a user-created FBO as an argument to a method, it would also accept the default FBO just the same. But if the price to pay for this is a trip to CPU and back to GPU (a trip which would be mostly 'hidden' to the user of my API) then no, I prefer to exclude the screen then.